# Toggle between checkboxes in VF Page

Tags: visualforce

I am new to VF and need idea on toggling between three checkboxes.

Is it better to use Radio button in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apex:selectRadio`. Here is the example from salesforce docs:

> Unlike checkboxes, only one radio button can ever be selected at a
>   time.

```
<!-- Page: -->
<apex:page controller="sampleCon">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:selectRadio value="{!country}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!items}"/>
            </apex:selectRadio><p/>
            <apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!test}" rerender="out" status="status"/>
     </apex:form>
     <apex:outputPanel id="out">
          <apex:actionstatus id="status" startText="testing..."> 
             <apex:facet name="stop"> 
               <apex:outputPanel> 
                  <p>You have selected:</p> 
                 <apex:outputText value="{!country}"/> 
              </apex:outputPanel> 
            </apex:facet> 
          </apex:actionstatus> 
     </apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class sampleCon {
    String country = null;

    public PageReference test() {
        return null;
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('US','US')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('CANADA','Canada')); 
        options.add(new SelectOption('MEXICO','Mexico')); return options; 
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) { this.country = country; }
}
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_selectRadio.htm)